# How to control the property rand_mode in a SystemVerilog class?

Tags: class, constraints, system-verilog

Suppose there is a class `A` like below:

```
class A;
rand logic [3:0] a;
rand logic [3:0] b;
rand logic [3:0] c;
constraint a_const{
    a<'h4;
}
constraint b_const{
    b<'h4;
}
endclass
```

When I use :

```
A at = new();
at.b_const.constraint_mode(0);
assert(at.randomize());
```

`b` is also randomized. But, I don't want that.

Is there a way I can only randomize `a` without randomizing `b` and `c`?

Because there can be many logics in a class, sometimes I just want to rand some of them. Put some of the logics in one class like A  while some in other class B is one of the solutions, but it is too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one of the `rand` variables in a class to be randomized, then you can pass the variable to the `randomize` function:

```
assert(at.randomize(a));
```

Alternately, as you mentioned in the title to your question, you can use `rand_mode` to disable randomization of individual class variables:

```
at.b.rand_mode(0);
at.c.rand_mode(0);
assert(at.randomize());
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18.8 *Disabling random variables with rand_mode()*.

With either of the above approaches, only `a` will be randomized.

---

I suspect you expected `b_const.constraint_mode(0)` to disable randomization of variable `b`.  That line simply disables the named `constraint`, leaving `b` unconstrained.  This means that `b` will be randomized in your original code (which is what you observed).

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog gives you two mode controls `rand_mode()` and `constraint_mode`, and they operate independently. Active constraints must be satisfied regardless of whether the variables are random or not(state-variables).

You should probably separate the variables you want randomized into different groups of different classes and perhaps put them into a hierarchy.

If you only want to randomize one variable with a single constraint, use `std::randomize()`

`assert( std::randomize(a) with { a < 'h4;});`